# Is It Possibly to Access Firefox Save As Command Using JS?

Tags: javascript, file, firefox

I'm trying to figure out how to call the File Save As Command in Firefox 
(the one you get when you right click an image and save it) to save an image using JS (or if there is something else I can use, I would be grateful if you pointed me in that direction). I am looking for an example of how to open the Save As menu and pre-fill the file name field ... I've been searching furiously and have come up with zip. In my search I saw that you cannot directly save a file to disk, but is it impossible to call the save as function? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I'm not looking to make this code available to everyone, and the java script is client side, I'm just writing a small script to make saving photos a little easier in terms of naming them.

-Will

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this, and really you are trying to find a solution in a way that does not embrace the internet and the way people interact with content. What you are trying to do is call on Operating System operation from Javascript. If there were anyway this would be possible,  I don't think it is at all, it would be a very poor solution. Think about all the different Operating Systems Firefox is being used on. If you found a solution for Windows 7, what about an Apple Mac running Firefox?

What you should consider is that a User decides whether to Save something to their computer, not the programmer of the application. Provide a link to the file, most users know how to right click a link and select Save As. Add help tip explaining what to do as well.

To give a File a specific name or even start an automatic download when a User clicks or takes some kind of action, you can create a response from your server that is a PDF,Excel,Jpeg,Doc,Docx or many other files types. The server can load the file in memory and sent it as a response with the proper header information in the response.

For example to set a specific name for the file when the user downloads you can set your Response header with something like:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

Comment: Mr. Ogden, thank you very much for the response, I really appreciate it! I'm actually currently using a Mac running Firefox, and I'm selfishly writing this script to make my life a little easier when saving photos from certain websites. Your insight is still invaluable to me and I will keep it in mind for future projects! Thanks again for the speedy response, I really really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome, may you find all your solutions quickly and smoothly, though that will hardly actually ever happen in real life lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use the anchor element's `download` attribute to specify that a link is to be downloaded. Note that this is [not implemented in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download), Chrome, Firefox, and Opera currently support it

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement
>
> HTMLAnchorElement.download
>   Is a DOMString indicating that the linked
>   resource is intended to be downloaded rather than displayed in the
>   browser. The value represent the proposed name of the file. If the
>   name is not a valid filename of the underlying OS, browser will adapt
>   it. The value is a URL with a scheme like http:, file:, data: or even
>   blob: (created with URL.createObjectURL).

**Demo**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);
ctx.clearRect(45,45,60,60);
ctx.strokeRect(50,50,50,50);

var link = document.getElementById("link");

//Set href to the data url that you want downloaded
link.href = "http://placehold.it/350x350";
//set download to the default filename you want to use
link.download = "image.png";
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<a href="#" id="link">Click to download</a>
```

You can also specify a regular url to a file, but note that if the server sends a filename header: `Content-Disposition ... filename...` that it will overwrite whatever you have in the download attribute.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Evans!  You've given me some really good insight, and I really think this will help me get what I need!